# Dynamic Table Name in If/Else clause MySQL prepared statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass in a table name as variable along with some other variables and create an if else condition.

- First checking to see if `@getTable1`query is true where the rows deleted='1'
- If true then do nothing, else `update` my row with `@getTable2` deleted='1'

This is what I have so far but getting errors since my syntax is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(
  IN tableName VARCHAR(50), 
  IN cartName VARCHAR(11)
)
BEGIN
SET @getTable1 =
  CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", tableName, 
        " WHERE cartType='", cartName, "' AND deleted='1'");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @getTable1;
EXECUTE stmt1;

IF EXISTS @getTable1 (do nothing)
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @getTable2 =
  CONCAT("UPDATE deleted FROM ", tableName, 
        " SET deleted='1'");
 PREPARE stmt2 FROM @getTable2;
EXECUTE stmt2;
END
```

END

Comment: What is `IF EXISTS @getTable1` supposed to be doing?  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am trying to check if this query is true `CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", tableName, 
        " WHERE cartType='", cartName, "'");`

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this stored procedure?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto  Its stated in the question,  if the `select` statement is true, then `update`.

Comment: It does not make sense! The query returns a result set, probably with multiple columns and rows. What does "true" means in this result set?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto  `true` means does the row exist where deleted='1'.  if it returns a row then do nothing, else update the row to deleted='1'.

Comment: @BillKarwin not all rows,  just the particular row.  This is part of a query and I just wanted to get syntax correct.  updated question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want to know if the first SELECT query returned any results, use `SELECT COUNT(*)` and store it in a user-defined variable. If you don't use [SELECT...INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html), then it'll generate a result set and the stored procedure will return that.

```
SET @cartName = cartName;
SET @getTable1 =
  CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @deletedCount FROM `", 
        REPLACE(tableName, '`', '``'), 
        "` WHERE cartType=? AND deleted='1'");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @getTable1;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @cartName;
```

Also try to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use query parameters for values, and at least use backticks to delimit the table-name. Escape literal backtick characters in the tableName.

Once you have this result in the user-defined variable, check that variable to see if it's zero.

Review the syntax for UPDATE. There's no FROM keyword in an UPDATE statement. You don't name the column until the SET clause. When in doubt, check the syntax in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

```
IF @deletedCount = 0 THEN
BEGIN
  SET @getTable2 =
    CONCAT("UPDATE `", 
        REPLACE(tableName, '`', '``'), 
        "` SET deleted='1'"
        -- WHERE...?
   ); 
   PREPARE stmt2 FROM @getTable2;
  EXECUTE stmt2;
END
```

Is there supposed to be a WHERE clause for the `cartType` in your UPDATE? Seems like there should be, otherwise you'll update all rows for *all* cart types. Nothing in the syntax you use makes the update apply only to the matching rows from the first SELECT. Each SQL statement is context-free (MySQL does not support updatable cursors).

Comment: thank you for this! yes there will be a `where` but I wanted to keep the question as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your `IF` syntax is way off, however, for this you do not even need it.

Just `UPDATE` the row, and check, if it is needed after that.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE new_procedure(
  IN tableName VARCHAR(50), 
  IN cartName VARCHAR(11)
)
BEGIN
  PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('UPDATE deleted FROM ', tableName,
                           ' SET deleted = 1 WHERE cartType=''', cartName,
                           ''' AND deleted <> 1');
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

If you want to check whether an update is occurred, you can do this:

```
  -- Place this just after the EXECUTE statement:
  IF FOUND() THEN
    -- do your stuff if updated...
  ELSE
    -- do your stuff if not updated...
  END IF;
```

Comment: if I `update` and the row does not exist, the can i insert in the `ELSE` area of your answer?

Comment: In short: yes... But if you want to "insert if not exists", then see this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: But `insert...on duplicate key update` only works if your search criteria are for unique key or primary key columns. I'm guessing `cartType` and `deleted` are not suitable for this.

Comment: Well, `cartType` should be, or the `UPDATE` would update a whole bunch of rows.... OR there should be some other unique columns, that is omitted for simplicity...